# Rails: Sqlite with PG gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, rails-postgresql

I installed postgres on my Mac and tried it for the first time with Rails. I included gem "pg" and removed the sqlite3 gem (after all, why would you need the latter if using the former). However, when I tried to start the server I got this error message

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@rails321/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

So I included the sqlite3 gem again and now the server works fine, but I actually don't have any idea if my test app is using sqlite3 or pg?

a) Am I supposed to have the sqlite3 gem installed if I'm planning on using the pg gem?
b) If I'm only supposed to have one of the two installed, is there a way to find out which one my test app is currently using (since both of them are in the Gemfile)

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Can I paste your Gemfile here? Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: @Amit, rails 3.2.1, posted gemfile in OP

Comment: It sounds like its trying to load sqlite, yes the Gemfile would be helpful, also the database.yml is configured to use pg?

Comment: @Alex Marchant, you're right, I didn't change database.yml. Do you know how I can change it now? development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

Comment: @AlexMarchant thanks, I just created a new app with postgres and copied from there.

Comment: cool, good luck mate!  post back if you hit any hickups!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here was my database.yml when i was working with the pg gem, the adapter is actually called postgresql and there are a couple other differences in the settings, if you just copy and paste the code below and change the database names you should be pretty much ready (I used heroku, this worked there):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DATABASE_DEVELOPMENT
  pool: 5
  username: USER_NAME
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DATABASE_TEST
  pool: 5
  username: USER_NAME
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DATABASE_PRODUCTION
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

Comment: how do I know what my user name is for postgres?

Comment: thats done in the postgres server on your localhost machine, once you've gotten the postgres server up and running you should create a user and a database id check out here http://www.jonathandean.com/2011/08/postgresql-8-4-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/ if you're running mac

Comment: thanks, sadly I was hoping it'd be as simple as sqlite3 where it's all done for you. However, I tried CREATE USER and was told command not found.  I made another question if you want to earn some more SO points. Thanks in advance :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493257/postgres-creating-a-username

Comment: I assume once it is set up, I can use the same Username across all apps? but I'd create new database for each one...

Comment: ya i think so, honestly i switched to mongo before i really had a good grasp of it

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are installing two database in same environment - as per Gemfile

It may happen that you used sqlite and pg in different environment in one Gemfile.

if you want to use

```
gem 'sqlite3'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

So now I am using sqlite3 in development mode and in production I am using pg, so in your database.yml you need to place two connection, first for development mode and production mode

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: pg (please correct the adapter)
  database: 
  user:
  password:
```

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

*A) Am I supposed to have the sqlite3 gem installed if I'm planning on using the pg gem?*

**No, as you suspect you need the sqlite gem for sqlite and the pg gem for postgres**

*B) If I'm only supposed to have one of the two installed, is there a way to find out which one my test app is currently using (since both of them are in the Gemfile)*

**Yes.  Type: `rails db` and look at the output.**
Here's what you would get for postgres:

```
$rails db
psql (9.1.2)
Type "help" for help.
```

*C) Asked rhetorically: "Why would I need both?"*

Actually there are several scenarios where you would need **both**, which include, some existing data in one db some in another, converting an application from one to the other, etc.  It's true however that it's usually one or the other.