# Postgres: creating a username

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to get started with Postgres on Rails apps on Mac.  I made a new rails app called "shawsome" and in the database.yml file it created this

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: shawsome_development
  pool: 5
  username: shawsome
  password:
```

But the server wouldn't run because there's no role for "shawsome." Rails just seemed to have inferred the username from the name of my app.

I looked at postgres documentation and it talks about CREATE USER command

```
CREATE USER jonathan;
```

However, when I tried to do CREATE USER, it said CREATE comment not found.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, once it's in production (on Heroku) I'm assuming it will also need a username. Will that username remain the same? i.e. if it's configured on my machine, do I need to do anything extra on Heroku?

Comment: @TheDelChop Mac 10.6.8 (not Lion), I updated the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on TheDelChop's answer
After installation you can run the following in the terminal:

```
createuser -P
```

(The -P is to add a password)

It will ask you for name, password, whether they are a superuser, can create new roles, and can create new db's.  You probably won't need any of those permissions for rails.

Then create the database to run with the following role you created:

```
createdb -O ROLE_NAME_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP NEW_DATABASE_NAME
```

And viola, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use the pg binary command `createuser` in bash/zsh.  Just answer the questions they will ask you, and don't setup the database.yml for production, Heroku will take care of that.

Comment: but when I create the Rails app for PG, it automatically sets some settings (a database name based on the name of the app, a role that I don't really have etc) for the production database. Should I delete those? or just leave them?

Comment: looks like you don't need to specify production details, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#database_urls

Comment: Yes, heroku rewrites the config/database.yml for you - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql - @AlexMarchant link is no longer correct.